# Why did Kate have a dead zombie hand keeping the fire egress ajar?

Tags: plot-explanation, army-of-the-dead

Just before Deiter successfully opens the vault inside the casino, Kate climbs up the ladder, keeps dead zombie hand between the fire egress and the frame:

[image]

Why did Kate have a dead zombie hand keeping the fire egress ajar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Because she needed a way out to find Geeta.

As we see later, the fire egress **automatically locks** and needs a keycard to open it.

[image]

So she block the egress from closing so she can use it to get out and find her friend.